# How to make dataframeA None if A's Id exist in B

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

dataframeA, dataframeB
Id, name

if I want to make dataframeA's name None if Id exist in dataframeB

dataframA

```
ID, name
1   jake

2   kim
```

dataframe B

```
   ID, name
   1, None
```

result

```
ID, name
1   None

2   kim
```

> sub.apply(lambda x: None if x.ImageId in noimages_list else
>   x.EncodedPixels)

Comment: `dfa['name'] = dfa['name'].mask(dfa['Id'].isin(dfb['Id']))`?

Comment: I want to make it none

Comment: `dfa['name'] = dfa['name'].mask(dfa['ID'].isin(dfb['ID']), None)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
dfa['name'] = dfa['name'].mask(dfa['ID'].isin(dfb['ID']), None)
```

or

```
dfa.loc[dfa['ID'].isin(dfb['ID']), 'name'] = None
```